# jquery ui reference in the master page creates an error in the content page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In my Code , I have a master page for my asp.net website.

I also have content pages (aspx pages) and each content page has a javascript .js page which holds java script and jquery code for that page.

What I am seeing now is that on moving the jquery reference from the content page to the master page , the code in the javascript .js page (jquery)  is throwing an error, on moving to that page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I get

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tooltip'
```

I am using a jquery tool tip on one of the aspx pages and when I navigate  to the page I see the above error

Comment: jQuery core is referenced before jQuery UI in the master page?

Comment: Yes jQuery core is referenced before Jquery UI